# Sort choices of a form item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a script that adds a choice to a form question upon submission.  When added it shows up at the bottom.   How can I sort the list of choices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getChoices`([*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#getChoices())) to retrieve an array of all the existing choices you already have, push your [new choice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#createChoice(String)) in this array, [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) this array and finally add the sorted array of choices using `setChoices([])`([**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#setChoices(Choice))).

Following your comment, I went a bit deeper and found a possible way to do it. Below is a demo test code in which I add an item to a list and sort the items alphabetically.
In this example the list question was the fourth question, please adapt to your situation. (comments in code, step by step)

```
function sortList(){
  var f = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var list = f.getItems()[3]; // this was my test form configuration
  var choices = list.asListItem().getChoices();
  var newChoice = list.asListItem().createChoice('0000 option');// an example that should come first in the list of choices
  var sortedChoices = [];
  sortedChoices.push([newChoice.getValue(),newChoice]);// add to the array, order doesn't matter
  for(var n in choices){
    Logger.log(choices[n].getValue());
    sortedChoices.push([choices[n].getValue(),choices[n]]);// add all existing items    
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(sortedChoices));// see the unsorted content
  sortedChoices.sort(function(x,y){
  var xp = x[0];
  var yp = y[0];
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp > yp ? 1 : -1;//  sort on choice value only
});
  var resultChoices = [];
  for(var n in sortedChoices){
    resultChoices.push(sortedChoices[n][1]);// create a new array with only useful objects    
  }  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(resultChoices));// check in logger
  list.asListItem().setChoices(resultChoices);// update the form
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, the problem is that getChoices(*), get's objects, that includes both the value and the navigation.   So when you look at the array it is [choice, choice, choice], and therefor sort doesn't work.    I need to find a way to sort based on the values and not lose the navigation associated with it.

Comment: see edit please, there might be a simpler way to do it but at least it works as expected ;-)

Comment: Serge, it worked out great.  I just added the feature to my add-on CheckItOut.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification to the code posted by Serge, to simplify and fix the sort function to allow for direct sorting of choice array by value without having to create value array, sort, and recreate sorted array.   This also maintains the navigation data.

```
function sortList(){
  var f = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var list = f.getItems()[3]; // this was my test form configuration
  var choices = list.asListItem().getChoices();
  var newChoice = list.asListItem().createChoice('0000 option');// an example that should come first in the list of choices
  choices.push(newChoice);

  choices.sort(function(x,y){
    var xp = x.getValue();
    var yp = y.getValue();
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp > yp ? 1 : -1;//  sort on choice value only
});

  list.asListItem().setChoices(choices);// update the form
}
```